# How to store the values of element values but it is referencing final address

Tags: c++, string

when i am storing data into an array after performing parsing an xml file we have to store it in an array but here it stores like the final address of xml file i.e. it stores all the values but the problem is it all values are referencing to one address so i used vector now for getting all the values, so is there any possibility to get all the values without using any predefined methods.

My code is like,

```
while(attr){            
                if(!xmlStrcmp(attr->name,(const xmlChar *)"user")){
                    sprintf((char *)UserName.c_str(),"%s",attr->children->content);
                    std::cout<<"UserName: "<<UserName.c_str()<<"\t\t";
                    UN.push_back(UserName.c_str());
                }
                if(!xmlStrcmp(attr->name,(const xmlChar *)"password")){
                    sprintf((char *)Password.c_str(),"%s",attr->children->content);
                    std::cout<<"Password: "<<Password.c_str()<<std::endl;
                    PWD.push_back(Password.c_str());
                }
                attr=attr->next;
            }
```

even vectors also, i am getting same problem so how can i solve this.

Comment: why are you using `sprintf` ? Why not create a `vector<string>` and copy the values in to that? and why you don't want to use `vector`?

Comment: For multiple reasons, `sprintf((char *)UserName.c_str(),"%s",attr->children->content);`  <- this line doesn't just make Baby Jesus cry, it makes him kill kittens.

Comment: Even with @Naveen's edits, this question make almost no sense.  In English we have these things called **sentances**.

Comment: @John, **sentence** .. *ducks*  :)

Comment: @Moo:  Wut?  I spel gud.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are storing values somewhere in a `vector` that aren't supposed to be stored permanently.  In particular, this line:

```
UN.push_back(UserName.c_str());
```

Seems to be storing the result of `UserName.c_str()` into a `vector<const char*>`.  If you do this, then you'll run into trouble as soon as you modify the `UserName` string, or when that string goes out of scope.  The value of `c_str()` is pretty fragile - it's not valid after doing just about anything to the source string - and exists primarily so that you can take string data and pass it into C code that needs a `const char*` as an argument.

To fix this, I would suggest either explicitly copying the strings before inserting them into the vector:

```
UN.push_back(strdup(UserName.c_str());
```

(You don't have to use `strdup` here; it's just an example)

Alternatively, consider storing `std::string`s in the `vector`, which own the string resource they point at and don't have this problem.

Hope this helps!